# PyTorch - Tensors multiplication along new dimension

Tags: python, pytorch

Sorry if already asked, but I can't find the words to look for on Google.

Let's say I have a tensor `t1` of size `[a,b]` and a tensor `t2` of size `[c]`.

How can I output a tensor `t3` of size `[a,b,c]`, so that:

```
t3[0, :, 0] = t1[0, :] * t2[0]
t3[0, :, 1] = t1[0, :] * t2[1]
t3[0, :, 2] = t1[0, :] * t2[2]

...

t3[1, :, 0] = t1[1, :] * t2[0]
t3[1, :, 1] = t1[1, :] * t2[1]
t3[1, :, 2] = t1[1, :] * t2[2]
```

and so on, without a for loop ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [torch.kron](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.kron.html) will give a tensor a x b*c, then using [torch.Tensor.reshape](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.reshape) could map to a tensor a x b x c :

```
t3=torch.kron(t1,t2).reshape(a,b,c)
```